# link error when using shared memory with POCO

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, shared-memory, poco, poco-libraries

When I make a application with POCO, I found a strange thing about compile error.

I have add -lrt according to check others' similar issues. However, it still does NOT work.

> /usr/local/lib//libPocoFoundation.a(SharedMemory.o): In function
>   `Poco::SharedMemoryImpl::SharedMemoryImpl(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long,
>   Poco::SharedMemory::AccessMode, void const*, bool)':
>   SharedMemory.cpp:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to`shm_open'
>   SharedMemory.cpp:(.text+0x31b): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
>   /usr/local/lib//libPocoFoundation.a(SharedMemory.o): In function`
>   Poco::SharedMemoryImpl::close()': SharedMemory.cpp:(.text+0x666):
>   undefined reference to `shm_unlink' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status Makefile:17: recipe for target 'test' failed make: ***
>   [test] Error 1

Magically, if I add a dummy function as below.

```
int dummy()
{
    const char *memname = "sample";
    const size_t region_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    int fd = shm_open(memname, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (fd == -1)
        return -1;
    int r = shm_unlink(memname);
    if (r != 0)
        return -1;
}
```

It successfully is built.

I cannot understand why & would like to search the formal to avoid such strange workaround.
Is there anyone can help on it please?

Also, I have checked libPocoFoundation.a and find both

1. shm_open
2. shm_unlink

belong to **'The symbol is undefined'**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a linkage error. We need to see the failing linkage command to help you. Post the complete build log, unedited, in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2011#issuecomment-346490372) - the problem is the order of linked libraries (`-lrt` before `-lPocoFoundation`).